# how to use protocolbuffers from static lib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocol-buffers

i have followed this : http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers

i was able to compile the Person.proto file

got the .h and .m files added to to my static lib project (libIOS)

the UI Project references the libIOS

now when i compile i get the following errors in UI project

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PBExtensionRegistry", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libIOS.a(Person.pb.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PBGeneratedMessage", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Person in libIOS.a(Person.pb.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PBGeneratedMessage_Builder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Person_Builder in libIOS.a(Person.pb.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PBMutableExtensionRegistry", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libIOS.a(Person.pb.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PBUnknownFieldSet", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libIOS.a(Person.pb.o)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_PBGeneratedMessage.memoizedSerializedSize", referenced from:
      -[Person serializedSize] in libIOS.a(Person.pb.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_PBGeneratedMessage", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Person in libIOS.a(Person.pb.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_PBGeneratedMessage_Builder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Person_Builder in libIOS.a(Person.pb.o)
  "_computeInt32Size", referenced from:
      -[Person serializedSize] in libIOS.a(Person.pb.o)
  "_computeStringSize", referenced from:
      -[Person serializedSize] in libIOS.a(Person.pb.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

the project  libIOS complies fine no errors

the project UI gives the above errors

Comment: Have you added library to link with project?

Comment: thanks the link was done properly